# restricting the expression

Tags: regex

I am trying to write an expression which will allow :

1) Enter digits in the first five spots.

and

2) Enter of numbers and/or alphabets in the next 6 spots.

and

3) A check which validates that the total length is = 11 neither more nor less.

I am able to achieve the #1 & #2 through the below expression but not able to put a validation which checks for the total data to be exactly 11 neither less nor more. Can someone provide some inputs. Thanks

```
^([\d{5}]*[0-9a-zA-Z]{6})$
```

Comment: data means...u want to check digit that should not less then or more then 11?

Comment: And why are you using `*` ? Remove it and it will only be 11 :) `^\d{5}[0-9a-zA-Z]{6}$`

Comment: Why do you have the * if the 5 digits are required?

Answer (score 2):

This part is failing: `[\d{5}]*`.

It matches *"any digit, a `{`, a 5 or a `}`"* 0 or more times.

You must be looking for `\d{5}`, which means *"five digits"*

Comment: "any digit 5 times" or "any 5 digits"? The former implies that they're the same 5 digits.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want:

`^\d{5}[0-9a-zA-Z]{6}$`

Answer (score 0):

for single line you could specify that your match must happen at the end of the line as follows ...

```
^\s*([0-9]{11})\z
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

this [\d{5}]* is causing the problem. Use this-
/^[0-9]{5}[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}$/